# IntelliJ IDEA Find Usages not working on Groovy Enum values

Tags: intellij-idea

I need to find all places in my code that uses a particular enum value, when I right click on the value and choose Find Usages, the find results only return the enum value itself, not any of the places it is actually used. This used to work months ago, but don't understand why it doesn't work now, It makes it really difficult to work. Even re-indexing the project did not help.

Here is a screenshot of one of the find attempts, I know that it is used in the full codebase.

[image: DataType Enum]

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with a small sample project to reproduce this issue attached. Also attach the logs via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.

Comment: I cannot create a sample project, I am a contractor and the hours it would take I would not get paid and it is always impossible to recreate in just a small project. And in this case, I have tried to invalidate catches, update IDE, reindex and I still get above. My co-worker's IJ is working fine doing this, and so no idea what could be different.

Comment: Try File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings... and update to the latest version at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html or try 2024.1 Beta at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/.

Comment: OK, I was able to make a quick project

Comment: Took a few hours, but it is working now.